# Find the process PID that rebooted my system

Tags: debian-wheezy

I have a debian server and last week it 'magicaly' restarted, and since then it keeps restarting at certain time, usually at 00:00am or 5:00am. So I'm trying to find out what process is causing this issue. 
I checked the `syslog`, and `/var/log/messages` but find nothing about PID. My `crontab` is ok too, it's empty. 
Im using the following system.

> Linux -- 3.2.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.2.73-2+deb7u2 i686 
>   GNU/Linux 
>   *Debian GNU/Linux 7.9 (wheezy)*

The question is: How I can find if a process rebooted my system?
 Any help will be appreciated ;)

Comment: Is a (graceful ) shutdown/reboot triggered or a hard reset ? `/var/log/messages` should allow you to make such distinction. ..

Comment: @HBRuijn, probably a hard reset: At 00:50am i got this: `qla2xxx [0000:05:00.1]-8038:4: Cable is unplugged...`
And then, at the 5:24am this occurs: `Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset`

Comment: that's a qlogic card - is the server part of a cluster?

Comment: @Rob-d, We have two of that card, but we don't use them. Our server is a poweredgeR610 running Debian. The `last reboot` command return this: `reboot   system boot  3.2.0-4-686-pae  Thu May  5 06:49 - 08:50  (02:01)`

Comment: does the **last** command tell you anything?

Comment: Rob-d, `reboot system boot 3.2.0-4-686-pae Thu May 5 06:49 - 08:50 (02:01).`

Only this, Rob.